# Getting rounded value from a double result

Tags: c#, asp.net, rounding

I want to display the net amount of a calculation in two text boxes

if `netamount = 45.60`

**first textbox should show rounded value and
 next textbox should show what is rounded.**

I have earlier done this with c by a manual program of rounding and now my manager don't want me do something like that because he believes c# has all math in build functions. So please help me friends....

> I want to get the value that is
>   rounded not numbers after the decimal

---

**EDIT:** (by [drachenstern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109749/drachenstern) )

> i want to round a number with 10 precisions like 45.8456789990 and get a result like 46 in one textbox and 85 in another.

The asker has a number like `double pi = 3.14159265d;` and wants to end up with two message boxes after the fact: **[ Whole Number]** `3` and **[2 Decimal Places]** `14` and he wants to know how to best achieve this affect. He only knows that he will be given a double, but he does not know whether that number will have fractional values. He expects them to. *Hope this edit helps.*

Comment: Check out the Math.Round function

Comment: @karthikRatnam so you want to write your own code instead of trusting the libraries and you want to take longer to develop the same code? I would do the same as you rmanager were I him.

Comment: if i am confusing you all keep like this..i want to round a number with 10 precisions like 45.8456789990 and get a result like 46 in one textbox and 85 in another.    Can u guys get my question now...(if you have anyother suggestion then using a library ..please tell me that please)

Comment: @KarthikRatnam ~ next time edit your question **or** start with that example in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: oh. Sorry. I will edit it next time

Comment: @KarthikRatnam ~ See if that answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest for simplicity sake you make it three parts:

```
int wholeNumber; //for getting the left part of the number
int decimalPartTwoPlaces; //for assigning the right part to two characters
double pi = 3.14159265d;

wholeNumber = Math.Round(pi);
decimalPartTwoPlaces = Math.Round( ( pi - (double)wholeNumber ) * 100 ); // cast so it doesn't try and truncate the pi part
```

And that should have the values that you want. I've not tested it but it looks right. Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll run it on my box and debug it.

Comment: It works. I dont know that math.round can be used like this too. This is new to me. Thanks. for clearing my question and giving the answer too. Since andrew suggested that there is no real math function do the solution... i will produce this as my output to my manager. Let he decide. :)

Comment: Well this is the case IF you need them in two text boxes. There are actually several ways to do this. But they will all work in about the same amount of time.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Why did you remove the answer, did it not work?

Comment: That's fine. If it didn't work I wanted to help you find out why not.

Answer (score 4):

Math.Round? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx

After @drachenstern clarified:

```
Math.Round(value, 2)
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx

Comment: no no man...i know math.round function i am not asking that.... I am asking how to get the rounded value ....  round function is in c too . I am asking how to get the value that is rounded. Can you understand that  (and b/w who gave 3 ups for this simple answer :(

Comment: I don't understand what a "rounded value" is then - can you explain/provide an example? What I understood is that in the above example, the left text box should contain 45 and right 60. If not, what should it contain?

Comment: left should have 46 and right should be 60 is okay. how will you get the value 60 using math.round is my question?

Comment: Not directly, but: `45.60 - Math.Truncate(45.60) = 0.60`

Comment: but why msdn says --public static decimal Truncate(
 decimal d
)
Truncate rounds d to the nearest integer towards zero.

Comment: @KarthikRatnam ~ That's what @icyrock's example demonstrates... Why not just take the `(int)46.60` portion of the code and then subtract the int from the float?

Comment: what i have implemented is not logically correct ..that is the problem drachenstern ..the logic is to get the rounded value of a number but not to get a number after the decimal part...can you understand the real world situation..where we get a double with 10 precision or so ..will you display the .34252523 itself in textbox?

Comment: ooooh, ok, I see what you want now.

Comment: @Karthik So When you get 45.123456 you want 45 in left and 12 in right, correct? If so, do something like Math.Round(value, 2).

Comment: Well technically HE clarified, I just edited his question for him ;)

Comment: the answer you provided was only working for first textbox output ...the second textbox output code was wrong... can u produce the same code again ..so that i can check and edit as i need

Comment: @icyrock... I am looking for decimal part output not the first textbox...your answer has only one value ...how can i get the right text value from your code ?

Comment: Thanks icyrocks ... for your prolong answers... I learned a lot about math.round and double conversions.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done simply matematically by first rounding, then substracting and multiplicating by 100 (if you wan't the two first decimals), then rounding again like this:

```
double pi = 3.14159265d;
int integerParth = (int)Math.Round(pi); // 3(int)
double decimalPoint = pi - integerPart; // 0.1415...(double)
int decimalPart = (int)Math.Round(decimalPoint * 100); // 14
```

Comment: Sorry i think you both have given a wrong answer ... i suspect... for 40.69 its is giving - 31 as the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Math functions in c# cannot gives your expected value

I tried your input 45.60 using all math functions that work with rounding off values

Here is the output:

```
Truncate            45
Round           46
Ceiling             46
Floor           45
```

I think some other function other than these should be used to get a result like .60 in a textbox